# Google Analytics shows blank page

Tags: analytics

yesterday I received the google credentials from someone to set up something in their google analytics. When I head towards analytics I get this error.

I tried incognito mode in chrome and also safari with a clear cache. The user owning this account also has this problem on their machine.

Any idea anyone?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Solution: go to business.google.com. On the left side there is an menu for statistics. On this site I had to enable statistics und type in some information.